# Green's theorem applied over a parallelogram

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, vector-analysis, greens-theorem

Using Green's theorem, evaluate the line integral $$I=\int_Cx^2(x^2+y^2)dx+y(x^3+y^3)dy,$$ where $C$ is the parallelogram with vertices $(0,0), (1,0), (2,2), (1,2)$, traversed in that order.

My solution: Suppose $\textbf{g}(x,y)=x^2(x^2+y^2)dx+y(x^3+y^3)dy$. Note that $curl \ g =x^2y$. Green's theorem tells us the line integral is now equal to $\int\int_Rx^2ydxdy$.

To find the region $R$ note that $0\le y\le 2$ and $\frac{y}{2}\le x\le \frac{y+2}{2}$.

Hence the integral is $\int_0^2\int_{\frac{y}{2}}^{\frac{y+2}{2}}x^2ydxdy$.

Evaluating gives and answer of $\frac{19}{48}$. Is this solution correct?

Comment: This looks correct to me. Well done!

Comment: No that is not correct. While your set-up is correct, you have not evaluated the integral correctly. Please check your work. The answer should be $3$.